# How to set CHKDSK for drive C: in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bsod, reboot, chkdsk

I recently got a 0xc000007b error whenever I tried to run some application software.
I found that [CHKDSK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHKDSK) for C drive might be a solution. When I tried to do it from C drive properties, it said the drive was in use and asked to schedule CHKDSK at the next reboot. I clicked OK.

When I restart, I experience a [BSOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death). I waited for 10 minutes but still nothing happens. So I forced a shutdown (laptop) and again booted up the computer and got a BSOD for just 5 or 10 seconds and system boots and works with no problem.

I repeated all these steps four or five times and yet with the same results.

1. Is there any other way other than CHKDSK to solve the 0xc000007b error?
2. If not, why is CHKDSK not working at boot up? Can I force CHKDSK on drive C: to perform while the system is on?

Platform: Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Do you have a second computer? If you have remove the drive from the first computer and checkdisk it in an other computer. (Make sure that that other computer is up to date with all updates. - Just in case there is a virus somewhere. )

Comment: hold up... "then BSOD for just 5 or 10 seconds and system boots" do you mean that a BSOD comes up, and stays on the screen for 5 to 10 seconds, and then the computer continues to boot normally?  Or that you get a BSOD that stays on the screen for a few seconds and then the computer RESTARTS and functions normally?  Because if it doesn't restart after the BSOD... if the BSOD just appears for a few seconds and then goes away, that's more than likely an infection... not an error.

Comment: @Bon-Gart how do you find whether 'the computer Restarts after 5 or 10 seconds of BSOD' or not? because BSOD appears as soon as the dos screen-from where you get into safe mode.   If you mean whether the dos screen appears again after BSOD, its not.

Comment: @BonGart Yeah weird, could be a threatening splash screen

Comment: because a BSOD is a show stopper.  It's not a passing notification.  When your system gets to the point where Windows is killing everything that is going on and replacing it with a Blue Screen notification of what error has occurred and a message that it is dumping the contents of your memory to a file for analysis... it is not going to THEN continue to function normally.  Not without restarting

Comment: Try ComboFix from Safemode http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/

Comment: @BonGart Did run a lot of scans with norton, microsoft windows  security essiantials malwarebyte's anti malware windows bit defender, without any positive. so its not an infection

Comment: @You should also try cloud-based anti-virus programs. Although they may be slower than their common counterparts, they offer an up-to-date database with the latest virus definitions.

Comment: Thank you all for trying to help me. I got this problem(0xc000007b error) solved i don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

For the header question, simply issue `chkdsk` and checking will be scheduled to run on reboot.

In this paricular scenario, the reason chkdsk can't do its job is during the bootstrap process, before Windows is fully operational, it has to load drivers first. A bad driver can cause BSOD, so Windows loading will halt and chkdsk will not run.

You should boot into safe mode and open [Device Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager), disable each suspect device one at a time and then follow that with a reboot until the BSOD is gone. But this is a pedestrian solution. The problem is printed at the BSOD output. Gather the information printed on the screen and search the Internet for the solution to your BSOD.

Try this solution for the 0xc000007b error: *[0xc000007B Error - The Application Failed To Initialize Properly](http://www.personalcomputerfixes.com/general-errors/0xc000007b-error%C2%A0-the-application-failed-to-initialize-properly%C2%A0/)*

See if that stops the BSOD. But as per the Wikipedia article *[Blue Screen of Death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death)* and personal experience, BSOD is hardware or driver related.

Comment: But, on scheduling on reboot, BSOD happens. since BSOD happens only while chkdsk is scheduled on re-boot, i have to come to conclusion that chkdsk itself causes BSOD, in which case i cannot succesfully carry out chkdsk by scheduling it on reboot.  Oh yeah i forgot safe mode. i'll try that and reply

Comment: @BonGart sorry i was wrong, after BSOD system restarts and functions normally

Comment: Not going to schedule a chkdsk anymore. not even once. even for testing. its really a pain in the a**. chkdsk is the sole reason for BSOD. So now, BSOD is not my problem. Only 0xc000007b error. I have to figure out a way other than chkdsk to eliminate this error. I hope there is an alternative.   BTW, the link you provided for this purpose is not a solution to me.

Comment: Ah i forgot to add this, even safe mode not works (due to BSOD) when chkdsk is scheduled. I also tried windows diagnostic repair tool during boot up. that too didn't help.

Comment: I don't know how but the 0xc000007B Error doesn't happen anymore. I didn't do anything specifically to eliminate this. Just did reboot a few times because of BSOD. i think my problem is solved, at least temporarily.

Comment: Just for sake of learning i'm continuing:(1) you said to boot from a live USB & move chkdsk.exe from windows folder.Why should i use live USB when i can move the chkdsk.exe by booting normally(since BSOD doesn't happen when i don't schedule chkdsk, i don't find any problem in booting). (2) //To stop Windows from running chkdsk, and perhaps stop the BSOD, move chkdsk to another location// why would i want to stop chkdsk? chkdsk runs on boot-up only if i schedule it. else it doesn't run while booting. So, if i am not scheduling chkdsk, there is no need/no way to stop it.  Thank you for your help

Comment: Pardon me for not getting a good picture of your problem. But hey, assuming that your problem is solved by now, just forget about the crap I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

If for whatever reason you cannot schedule `CHKDSK` just insert a windows install disk, and run it from there. (repair -> command prompt)

Answer (score 0):

Reboot PC and use key F8, It'll give you a advanced boot options, selelect there `Repair your computer`, after it boots it'll show a menu, there select `command prompt`.
As command appears you can run `chkdsk` from there on disk c:

Comment: I just tried this and chkdsk still aborts with an error message saying the drive is write protected.

Answer (score -1):

At this point, you will have to boot into a Windows DVD, and you can run CHKDSK from there, but then you also need to remove the CHKDSK entry in your registry so it doesn't attempt to run again after you reboot... HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentControlSet/RunOnce...

Comment: This doesn't solve the author's question.  The author didn't want to run CHKDSK so why exactly are you telling him to run CHKDSK besides he already FIXED the problem.